# Restart application pool based on http response code

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will restart an application pool in IIS if a 503 response code is received.

So far I have managed to retrieve the response code for every crm application under the default website in IIS. However I am unsure how I would go about finding the application pool name. I've tried the below, but it returns the same application pool for each site. Can anyone help?

```
$getSite = (Get-WebApplication -Site 'Default Web Site')
$SiteURL = ForEach ($site in $getSite.path) {("http://localhost")+$site}
ForEach ($crm in $SiteURL){
$req = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($crm)
try {
   $res = $req.GetResponse()
 } catch [System.Net.WebException] {
   $res = $_.Exception.Response
 }
$ApplicationPool = ForEach ($app in $getSite.applicationpool) {$app}  
 if([int]$res.StatusCode -eq 503)  {write-host ($crm + ' ' +  [int]$res.StatusCode) + $app}
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to access `$_.Exception.InnerException` for the the `Response` property.

Your `$ApplicationPool` assignment doesn't make much sense, as you would only need one `applicationPool` name per `$crm` app you test:

```
foreach($App in @(Get-WebApplication -Site 'Default Web Site')){

    # Uri for the application
    $TestUri = 'http://localhost{0}' -f $App.path

    # Create WebRequest
    $Request = [system.Net.WebRequest]::Create($TestUri)
    try {
        # Get the response
        $Response = $Request.GetResponse()
    } catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        # If it fails, get Response from the Exception
        $Response = $_.Exception.InnerException.Response
    }

    # The numerical value of the StatusCode value is the HTTP status code, ie. 503
    if(503 -eq ($Response.StatusCode -as [int])){
        # Restart the app pool
        Restart-WebAppPool -Name $App.applicationPool
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this works really well. Thanks a lot for your help.